# In ExtJS, how to handle master detail with updates to both tables

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

The problem I'm trying to find the best solution for involves the standard scenario of a master table (orders for example) and a details table (orderlines).  Both in separate tables.  From the server, I can produce both json nested data and two separate entities.  On my client (ExtJS) side I need to both display the nested data with a template as well as be able to do CRUD operations on both the orders and the details.

I have two solutions, neither of which I like.  I'm preparing training material and want to offer the students an excellent solution, not one full of peril.  Here are the two I've come up with.

**Scenario 1**

> Create a two models and one store using the associations tag
>   (belongsTo and hasmany).  This works perfect for viewing the data,
>   however the CUD of CRUD is really miserable for me.  Maybe I am
>   missing something but it seems you have to implement custom readers
>   and do many unnatural things to make this work.

**Scenario 2**

> Create two models and two stores.  Implement a filter on the details
>   store so that when a the master table (grid) changes row selection,
>   the details table (grid) gets filtered.  This makes creating a nested
>   view for the template a little awkward because you have to build the
>   json object yourself, but the bigger problem is that you have to load
>   all your details ahead of time and filter on those on each master row
>   selection.  Or, you can do a

nother ajax request on every row change which makes the client not very performant.

I'd love to hear a better solution or how one of my scenarios could be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In similar problem in my application I am going with your scenario 1. What problems are you having with this?

The only issue I had was that association data was not getting sent to server on model.save. And the workaround was adding a Json Writer override.

```
Ext.define('SampleApp.config.CustomJsonWriter', {
    override: 'Ext.data.writer.Json',

    getRecordData: function (record) {
        var associatedData = record.getAssociatedData();

        record.associations.each(function (item, index) {
           var obj = {};
           obj[item.name] = associatedData[item.name];
           Ext.apply(record.data, obj);

        });

        return record.data;
    }
});
```

Hopefully, Sencha will include a flag for including association data in future ExtJS versions. But the workaround is quite simple as you can see.

Comment: looks nice.  I will try that.  Will this work with nested? (trying to wrap my head around that), that is customers have orders, orders have line items.

Comment: In v5.1, The above code and variations of it error at startup with "Uncaught Error: Cannot override method getRecordData on Ext.data.writer.Json instance.".  The workaround (with unknown consequences) is to add $configStrict: false to your config object.